# How can i connect to Jenkins remotely using username and password?

Tags: jenkins

Currently i connect to Jenkins using

```
 http://<server_ip>:<port>/
```

How can i connect using username and password that is validated on the Jenkins service like the following ?

```
http://<username>:<password>@<server_ip>:<port>/
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you want to remotely perform some operations on Jenkins?

Comment: user connect to Jenkins remotely via http://<server_ip>:<port>/. They can then view the jobs and login. I have implemented Project-based Matrix Authorization Strategy. But i want to restrict remotely browsing or connecting to Jenkins unless it is authenticates against a Jenkins User. So basically if it is not a valid user they cant remotely connect.  In reading docs on Jenkins , it doesnt seem to show how i can restrict remotely browsing